# How to set value but also keep type info in class membership declaration

Tags: typescript

I have this class:

```
export class HavenHandler implements IHavenHandler {


  opts: {
    auto: true
    handleGlobalErrors: true;
    revealStackTraces: true
  }

 // as opposed to:

  opts: {
    auto: boolean
    handleGlobalErrors: boolean;
    revealStackTraces: boolean
  }


}
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
 opts: {
    auto: true as boolean
    handleGlobalErrors: true as boolean;
    revealStackTraces: true as boolean
  }
```

so that later I can switch them to false if needed. But as of now, the compiler won't allow me to mutate them to false.

Comment: What you've shown is a type annotation, not an initializer. If you want `boolean`, use `boolean`. By using `true`, you've specifically said the type will be `true`. Did you mean `opts = {` rather than `opts: {`? (If you do that, `opts` will have an initial value and the individual flags in it will be of `boolean` type, so you can change them.) https://tsplay.dev/mqqyRm If that's not what you meant, could you create a [mre] in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to declare the type of the property as well as set a default value, you can do something like this:

```
class HavenHandler {
  opts: {
    auto: boolean;
    handleGlobalErrors: boolean;
    revealStackTraces: boolean
  } = {
    auto: true,
    handleGlobalErrors: true,
    revealStackTraces: true
  }
}
```

THis will allow you to manipulate the boolean values.
[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4AkUDdgB2OBAJksFHAPQBUcAlgLZjmOEyYCSO%20RKp5SjSpwA3gCg4UuBDAc4AXjGTpqlAFcYEAFxwYUdcAA0K1VIAW-MsADiSCACMUSAKJQo0NLv2GTZ6VDA%20M4AyjAoCADWACpQEcBeegbGpnAAvgDc4qkkECEQbDDm9AQA5gAUAJTK-lJF9GgAdLIcjRpainAAZs5owFmqaeJpQA)

Comment: FWIW: There's no need for that type annotation, that's exactly the type TypeScript will infer from the initializer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder in this case I think youre right